# How to measure the refresh rate of a display in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es2

I am working on OpenGL ES application which is rendering 60 frames per second which is equal to my Monitor refresh rate.

My problem is: if I make Swapinterval 0, I am getting a FPS value above 200. I am able to reduce it to 60, but I have taken this value statically (from the command line, or hard coded).

How to calculate the refresh rate of the monitor programmatically so that I can control FPS?

Comment: What is your end-goal?

Comment: You can wait for vsync to begin rendering

Comment: To have your accounts merged, visit [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) page, this will allow you to comment on your questions and their answers.